# Index Subset of Array in For Loop in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I have a question regarding indexing and loops in MATLAB. I have a vector of length *n* (named *data* in the code below). I want to examine this vector 4 elements at a time inside of a for loop. How can I do this? My attempt included below does not work because it will exceed the array dimensions at the end of the loop.

```
for k = 1:length(data)

    index = k:k+3;

    cur_data = data(index);

    pre_q_data1 = cur_data(1);
    pre_q_data2 = cur_data(2);
    % Interweaving the data
    q = [pre_q_data1; pre_q_data2];
    qdata = q(:)';


    pre_i_data1 = cur_data(3);
    pre_i_data2 = cur_data(4);

    i = [pre_i_data1; pre_i_data2];
    idata = i(:)';

end
```

Comment: You need to stop when `k+3` is equal to the last index of the array, not when it's equal to `end+3`.

Comment: Also you can get rid of the `for-loop` and use `buffer` instead. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html).

Comment: @kedarps, * "Also you can [...] use `buffer` instead *if you have the signal processing toolbox*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have `k` go all the way to `length(data)` if you're planning on indexing up to `k+3`.

I've also taken the liberty of greatly simplifying your code, but feel free to ignore that!

```
for k = 1:length(data)-3
    % maximum k = length(data)-3, so maximum index = length(data)-3+3=length(data)
    index = k:k+3;
    cur_data = data(k:k+3);
    % Interweaving the data
    q = cur_data(1:2); % transpose at end of line here if need be
    i = cur_data(3:4); % could just use data(k+2:k+3) and not use cur_data
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Sometimes the simplest solutions fly right over your head.